# load separeted cshtml file in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am learning asp.net core and I started a new webapp project.

Currently, I separate my `sidebar.cshtml` from `_Layout.cshtml` because it is too long to read.
I wonder how can I load my `sidebar.cshtml` in the `_Layout.cshtml`.

The `sidebar.cshtml` and the `_Layout.cshtml` are in the same folder - `Shared`.

I've tried something like this in `_Layout.cshtml` but it didn't go well:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".sidebar").load("sidebar.cshtml");
    });
</script>
<div class="sidebar">
</div>
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your need to take `sidebar.cshtml` as `partial view`. Then in `_Layout.cshtml`, add this `partial view` like as following...

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <partial name="sidebar.cshtml" /> @*in case of sidebar.cshtml in Shared folder.*@
</div>
```

Finally, run the project & enjoy.